# Gmail - how to override user agent stylesheet?

Tags: image, gmail, newsletter

So, my email looks fine in Outlook but crappy in Gmail. Images are getting extra space around them. I have tried the display:block solution but it didn't work. Using Firebug you can see that Gmail adds a paragraph to the images, and this paragraph has padding set to it (See attachment). So I tried overwriting their rules by applying "p {-webkit-margin-before: 0!important;-webkit-margin-after: 0!important;}" in the  section- Still didn't work. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So it must be an Outlook thing. When I sent it through there I had the gaps in Gmail. When I used Mailchimp to send with the exact same markup, the gaps had gone. Hoorah.